# Debian 9 openjdk-7-jre and openjdk-7-jre-headless

Tags: debian, java

Need to use a program that requires openjdk7. Running Debian 9 Mate.

Get the following when I try to install

```
$sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-7-jre-headless : Depends: tzdata-java but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Try using openjdk-8-jre instead.  Seriously.  Most programs written in Java will run with the latest version of Java.  Java 7 is no longer supported by the "upstream" source.  It was EOLed a couple of years ago.

Comment: According to the openjdk8-aarch64 port's README, openjdk7 is *required* as the bootstrap jdk to compile openjdk8. I can't find any other sources to confirm this, though.

Answer (score 0):

The package `openjdk-7*` is not available for Debian stretch through `apt`, it is only available for Debian [jessie , Sid and experimental](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/openjdk-7-jdk) .

The correct package version is [`openjdk-8-jdk`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/openjdk-8-jdk) and [`openjdk-8-jre-headless`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/openjdk-8-jre-headless) , to install it on debian 9 run:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Comment: installing jre 8 is not a solution for an application that runs on jre 7

Comment: @HassanALAMI The safe way is to install the 2 packages on debian Jessie. Installing `openjdk-7-jdk` and `openjdk-7-jre-headless` from Debian Sid will break your system and the installation from the experimental repository isn't possible because of the unsatisfiable dependencie `libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12)`.

Comment: Well, what if you have a program that claims jvm 7 when running ?